# Can't hear game audio when streaming PS3 with Elgato HD60S+ and OBS

Tags: ps3, streaming, hdmi, obs

While I broswe into XMB I can hear the "clicking sound" on OBS, without any issue. As soon as I launch any game, audio completely disappear from OBS.

**Connection: PS3 Super slim --> HDMI splitter --> Elgato HD60S+**

What I've tried:

- Replace all cables
- Different games or applications. (I can hear music or videos sounds)
- Change audio setup on console, removed Dolby5.1 and added AAC
- Setting 720p as resolution didn't helped
- PS3 --> Splitter --> TV/Monitor connection works flawlessly
- 4K Capture Utility failed completely with a "no signal" warning

**So basically, PS3 audio on OBS works perfect until I launch any type of game, after it, complete silence, also XMB goes "muted" until I restart the console.**

Could be a faulty Elgato? Never had problems with others consoles, like PS4.
Bad splitter? Why let me hear and see until I launch a game then?
I've installed PS3 Hen and Multiman, everything up to date.

EDIT: I am currently using a splitter that bypass HDCP

Comment: What about 2ch LPCM?

Comment: @hobbs tried that too with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection)(wikipedia link), and here's explanation on [Elgato Support page](https://help.elgato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040482032-HDCP-and-Elgato-Game-Capture-devices#h_01G2MFSAAXKYW1R5YC502ZQC0J) (it also states that capturing PS3 isn't supported).

Since you can hear XMB sound when you're not playing game, Elgato isn't problem here (and you seem to be able to hear sounds on PS4 too). They just don't support it. It might be possible to bypass HDCP with some so-called HDCP bypass splitter, but I don't much know about that hardware, so I just mention it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a splitter to avoid that problem. The splitter I am using, bypass HDCP, if HDCP was the problem, I would not see any signal on OBS